# a=3,2,1; gives error in gcc

Tags: c, gcc, variable-assignment, comma-operator

I tried the following code in gcc:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a=3,2,1;//////////////////////ERROR!//////////////////////////
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected it to compile successfully as:

- a series of integer expressions seperated by commas will be evaluated from left to right and the value of the right-most expression becomes the value of the total comma separated expression.

Then, the value of the integer variable a should have been 1 right? Or is it 3?

And why am I getting this error when I try to execute this program?

> error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant

Comment: it's neither 1 or 3, it's a syntax error

Comment: There is no comma-operator. The comma is part of the declaration.

Comment: @Gabriel: No research effort?

Comment: @Olaf Maybe. But if it is the point here, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery?rq=1) should not have so many up votes (it is just an example).

Comment: @Gabriel: So you mean, once a posting has an upvote, there shall be no downvoters? Feel free to start e feature-request on meta for that ... (but then, please also for the other direction!)

Comment: @Olaf This is not even close to what I mean. My point is: A question with low research effort can be a good question (so I used that another question as an example). This question here is interesting and well written, thus does not deserve a down vote.

Comment: @Gabriel: Please read site-rules. No research effort is a valid DV reason. Anyway, if you want to criticise on DVs, please do that on meta, not here in comments. Fee free to post a link to your meta-question. Until then: case closed!

Comment: @Olaf, first, you intentionally misinterpret what I said, then you dare to shut me out. You are not the kind of person I want to have a conversation with. Bye.

Comment: I "shout you out"? Where? By pointing you at site-rules and telling to use the section which is exactly meant for such problems? But good you know what I understand from your comments. I'm not that good, I'm no clairvoyant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you separate the initialization from the declaration, you may get what you expected:

```
int a;
a = 3, 2, 1;     // a == 3, see note bellow
```

or

```
int a;
a = (3, 2, 1);   // a == 1, the rightmost operand of 3, 2, 1
```

as your original command is syntactically incorrect (it is the **declaration** so it expected other variables to declare instead of numbers `2` and `1`)

> **Note**: All side effects from the evaluation of the left-operand are completed before beginning the evaluation of the right operand.

So

```
a = 3, 2, 1
```

which are 3 comma operators `a = 3`, `2` and `1` are evaluated from left to right, so the first evaluation is

```
a = 3, 2
```

which result 2 (right-operand) (which is by the way *not assigned* to *any* variable, as the value of the left-operand `a = 3` is simply `3`), but **before giving this result** it is completed the side effect `a = 3` of the left-operand, i. e. assigning `3` to variable `a`. (Thank **AnT** for his observation.)

Comment: @J...S at least for me, `a=3,2,1;` results in `a==3` and `a=(3,2,1);` results in `a==1`. I don't know enough to know if this is implementation-defined behavior or not. For both cases, `gcc` warns "operand of comma expression as no effect". I can't think of a practical reason for ever doing this.

Comment: @MarianD: "... get what you expected"? What exactly do you think the OP expected? The original post suggests that the OP expected their code to behave as `int a = (3, 2, 1);`. But your `a = 3, 2, 1;`, is actually `(a = 3), 2, 1;`, which is completely different. It compiles, but the behavior is stiull different from the OP expectations.

Comment: @MarianD Oops! Your code int a; a = 3, 2, 1; does compile but when I tried int a = 3, 2, 1; it still showed error? Why? What's the difference?

Comment: Compare: `int a = 3, b, c` (correct - declaration of 3 variables, the 1st is initialized) and `int a = 3, 2, 1` (incorrect - `2` and `1` **are not correct names for variables**.

Comment: @J...S: The difference has already been explained to you. `int a = 3, 2, 1;` is grouped by grammar as `int (a = 3), 2, 1;`, which is (informally speaking) equivalent to `int a = 3; int 2; int 1;` These last `int 2; int 1;` bits make no sense, which is the reason for the error.

Answer (score 12):

That's parsed as a three-part variable declaration, with two invalid variables.

You need to wrap the entire initializer in parentheses so that it's parsed as a single expression:

```
int a=(3,2,1);
```

Comment: When the heck does someone use this?

Comment: @OmidCompSCI: To do evil things in expressions.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Comment: thanks for the link, it is quite funny I have never seen the "comma" operator used like this. Usually the most advanced thing I have seen is in for loops with multi-conditional statements;

Comment: @Omid CompSCI: As for `for` loops, most of the time it would be used in the first or third part of the `for` header. It would be rather strange to see it used in the conditional part.

Comment: @AnT yes that is what I meant sorry, everything but the termination condition.

Comment: @AnT and thanks for the link, in my opinion I would not opt out for readability just for writability. I think people that use this have not read the book Clean Code.